# LetsEncrypt Renewal failed authentification procedure when I set 301 Redirect in Nginx vhost (SOLVED)

Tags: nginx, redirect, lets-encrypt, http-status-code-301, certbot

On Ubuntu Server 18.04.04, Nginx 1.14.0, with LetsEncrypt certbot install via apt (not snap)

When I set a 301 redirect to another domain, I have this message :

```
Attempting to renew cert (domain1.fr) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain1.fr.conf produced an unexpected error: Failed authorization procedure. domain1.fr (http-01): urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized :: The client lacks sufficient authorization :: (MY IP): Invalid response from https://www.domaine2.fr/targetpage: "<!DOCTYPE html>\n    <!--[if lt IE 7]><html class=\"no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7\"> <![endif]-->\n    <!--[if IE 7]><html class=\"no-js". Skipping.
```

when i attempt a renewal simulation with :

`sudo certbot renew --dry-run`

Yet, my declaration for LetsEncrypt is placed before the redirect directive.

Below, it's my virtual host config for domain1.fr :

```
server {
    server_name domain1.fr;
    listen 80;

    # Path for first deliverance of LE certificate, and renewal
        location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/html/certbot/.well-known;
    }
    # Proxy params
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_general_test;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_compression;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/errors_pages_new;

    # Redirect to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name domain1.fr;
    listen 443 ssl;

    # Path for first deliverance of LE certificate, and renewal
        location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/html/certbot/.well-known;
    }

    # Proxy params
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_general_test;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy_compression;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/errors_pages_new;

    # SSL LE
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect to another website
    return 301 https://www.domaine2.fr/targetpage;

    # ModSecurity
    modsecurity on;
    modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;

    # Logs
```

How I can managed certbot-auto while keeping my redirect ?
I didn't find solution when i search on the web...

Thanks,
Best Regards

Comment: Wrap the `return 301 ...` inside a `location / { ... }` block, otherwise your `location /.well-known` block will not work.

Comment: Thanks Richard ! Issue solved with your answer ;)
have a nice day,